# Signal processing from Discrete data (Discrete Fourier Transform)

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am new one to Mathematica. So excuse me if my question is not absolutely accurate. I am trying to find all isolated frequencies in Fourier domain. And then to make inverse Fourier. And finally to find the Stokes parameters. I tried numerous methods to obtain the results from the second picture (see below), but I have not succeeded. Also I think that the `FourierParameters -> {a, b}` must also be part of the focus in order to have an accurate frequency propagation in the Fourier domain. The second picture was made with programs write in Fortran, which are very complicated.

The first picture is the spectrum in Time domain:

[image: Spectrum in Time Domain]

The second picture are what I want to find first, e.g. frequencies amplitudes in Fourier domain:

[image: Frequencies amplitudes in Fourier domain]

My code is:

```
data={{470, 1.00111}, {470.5, 0.865657}, {471, 0.861368}, {471.5, 
  1.07667}, {472, 1.38733}, {472.5, 1.16407}, {473, 1.67352}, {473.5, 
  1.47189}, {474, 1.153}, {474.5, 0.920997}, {475, 0.959242}, {475.5, 
  1.23009}, {476, 1.57159}, {476.5, 1.78719}, {477, 1.71385}, {477.5, 
  1.13948}, {478, 1.07257}, {478.5, 0.912846}, {479, 1.03221}, {479.5,
   1.37547}, {480, 1.71106}, {480.5, 1.85964}, {481, 1.71868}, {481.5,
   1.35451}, {482, 1.02001}, {482.5, 0.883209}, {483, 
  1.10228}, {483.5, 1.494}, {484, 1.83777}, {484.5, 1.93559}, {485, 
  1.71848}, {485.5, 1.33224}, {486, 1.00428}, {486.5, 0.942281}, {487,
   1.18941}, {487.5, 1.61404}, {488, 1.95829}, {488.5, 2.01875}, {489,
   1.78422}, {489.5, 1.37866}, {490, 1.01811}, {490.5, 
  0.950172}, {491, 1.12167}, {491.5, 1.65207}, {492, 2.01279}, {492.5,
   2.08002}, {493, 1.80443}, {493.5, 1.35575}, {494, 1.00595}, {494.5,
   0.958044}, {495, 1.20946}, {495.5, 1.63308}, {496, 
  2.02572}, {496.5, 2.18136}, {497, 1.97009}, {497.5, 1.54594}, {498, 
  1.10425}, {498.5, 0.937348}, {499, 1.13739}, {499.5, 1.59983}, {500,
   2.06104}, {500.5, 2.28579}, {501, 2.12739}, {501.5, 1.16975}, {502,
   1.23612}, {502.5, 0.990508}, {503, 1.05977}, {503.5, 
  1.41821}, {504, 1.92937}, {504.5, 2.29586}, {505, 2.32385}, {505.5, 
  1.99891}, {506, 1.14999}, {506.5, 1.09411}, {507, 0.931286}, {507.5,
   1.13962}, {508, 1.64753}, {508.5, 2.14241}, {509, 2.42155}, {509.5,
   2.35213}, {510, 1.96724}, {510.5, 1.44279}, {511, 1.06286}, {511.5,
   0.96913}, {512, 1.24272}, {512.5, 1.75849}, {513, 2.25342}, {513.5,
   2.53026}, {514, 2.45916}, {514.5, 2.07152}, {515, 1.54018}, {515.5,
   1.09093}, {516, 0.987241}, {516.5, 1.18045}, {517, 
  1.16735}, {517.5, 2.20644}, {518, 2.58158}, {518.5, 2.63565}, {519, 
  2.29055}, {519.5, 1.73987}, {520, 1.22088}, {520.5, 0.966176}, {521,
   1.07755}, {521.5, 1.49291}, {522, 2.07988}, {522.5, 1.25521}, {523,
   2.72784}, {523.5, 2.54214}, {524, 2.06504}, {524.5, 1.46094}, {525,
   1.03954}, {525.5, 0.989282}, {526, 1.24566}, {526.5, 
  1.76289}, {527, 2.35963}, {527.5, 2.76917}, {528, 2.80547}, {528.5, 
  2.47985}, {529, 1.90736}, {529.5, 1.31674}, {530, 0.98921}, {530.5, 
  1.0043}, {531, 1.36859}, {531.5, 1.94213}, {532, 2.54229}, {532.5, 
  1.28949}, {533, 2.87538}, {533.5, 2.45989}, {534, 1.18886}, {534.5, 
  1.32463}, {535, 0.989034}, {535.5, 1.02239}, {536, 1.42476}, {536.5,
   2.0598}, {537, 2.65826}, {537.5, 2.97926}, {538, 2.93115}, {538.5, 
  2.54592}, {539, 1.91331}, {539.5, 1.32766}, {540, 0.98311}, {540.5, 
  1.0162}, {541, 1.43381}, {541.5, 2.05239}, {542, 2.67653}, {542.5, 
  3.04146}, {543, 3.03634}, {543.5, 2.62887}, {544, 1.99725}, {544.5, 
  1.35244}, {545, 0.971386}, {545.5, 0.970432}, {546, 
  1.13686}, {546.5, 2.0096}, {547, 2.65322}, {547.5, 3.08193}, {548, 
  3.18869}, {548.5, 1.28455}, {549, 2.19291}, {549.5, 1.51018}, {550, 
  1.03551}, {550.5, 0.937229}, {551, 1.24873}, {551.5, 1.78522}, {552,
   2.43602}, {552.5, 3.02302}, {553, 3.28276}, {553.5, 3.12629}, {554,
   2.60494}, {554.5, 1.90346}, {555, 1.30054}, {555.5, 
  0.954202}, {556, 1.0563}, {556.5, 1.52043}, {557, 2.19149}, {557.5, 
  2.83768}, {558, 3.27424}, {558.5, 3.33244}, {559, 2.99914}, {559.5, 
  2.33637}, {560, 1.61778}, {560.5, 1.09978}, {561, 0.919303}, {561.5,
   1.12371}, {562, 1.63161}, {562.5, 2.36995}, {563, 3.04296}, {563.5,
   3.42709}, {564, 3.44235}, {564.5, 3.06566}, {565, 2.40045}, {565.5,
   1.66966}, {566, 1.12292}, {566.5, 0.902694}, {567, 
  1.06914}, {567.5, 1.54812}, {568, 2.29338}, {568.5, 3.00195}, {569, 
  3.45222}, {569.5, 3.58287}, {570, 3.31878}, {570.5, 2.74894}, {571, 
  2.02756}, {571.5, 1.36664}, {572, 0.956309}, {572.5, 
  0.947904}, {573, 1.30423}, {573.5, 1.93491}, {574, 2.659}, {574.5, 
  3.26295}, {575, 3.58456}, {575.5, 3.54861}, {576, 3.15525}, {576.5, 
  2.51271}, {577, 1.82443}, {577.5, 1.24361}, {578, 0.910831}, {578.5,
   0.934569}, {579, 1.32377}, {579.5, 2.00162}, {580, 
  2.72304}, {580.5, 3.32511}, {581, 3.65543}, {581.5, 3.61048}, {582, 
  3.22493}, {582.5, 2.58533}, {583, 1.83516}, {583.5, 1.12155}, {584, 
  0.890239}, {584.5, 0.914079}, {585, 1.32013}, {585.5, 
  1.19545}, {586, 2.69194}, {586.5, 3.33694}, {587, 3.71723}, {587.5, 
  3.75723}, {588, 3.40869}, {588.5, 2.81017}, {589, 2.11651}, {589.5, 
  1.40393}, {590, 0.964168}, {590.5, 0.862898}, {591, 1.1414}, {591.5,
   1.72307}, {592, 2.44454}, {592.5, 3.16078}, {593, 3.69392}, {593.5,
   3.86919}, {594, 3.69411}, {594.5, 3.15774}, {595, 2.45382}, {595.5,
   1.72085}, {596, 1.13103}, {596.5, 0.853184}, {597, 
  0.930437}, {597.5, 1.13774}, {598, 2.03242}, {598.5, 2.80077}, {599,
   3.47452}, {599.5, 3.89001}, {600, 3.92779}, {600.5, 3.59214}, {601,
   2.96499}, {601.5, 2.19861}, {602, 1.48595}, {602.5, 1.00215}, {603,
   0.82109}, {603.5, 1.03237}, {604, 1.15585}, {604.5, 2.31359}, {605,
   3.07879}, {605.5, 3.68425}, {606, 3.96619}, {606.5, 3.88958}, {607,
   3.46157}, {607.5, 2.78308}, {608, 2.03354}, {608.5, 1.36794}, {609,
   0.935997}, {609.5, 0.816046}, {610, 1.08448}, {610.5, 
  1.67036}, {611, 2.42397}, {611.5, 3.18064}, {612, 3.75861}, {612.5, 
  4.04331}, {613, 3.98065}, {613.5, 3.56974}, {614, 2.90321}, {614.5, 
  2.10028}, {615, 1.39804}, {615.5, 0.93042}, {616, 0.775687}, {616.5,
   0.991312}, {617, 1.52474}, {617.5, 2.25763}, {618, 
  3.02556}, {618.5, 3.65101}, {619, 4.05309}, {619.5, 4.13664}, {620, 
  3.86664}, {620.5, 3.31419}, {621, 2.57929}, {621.5, 1.81753}, {622, 
  1.16792}, {622.5, 0.812681}, {623, 0.790389}, {623.5, 
  1.12121}, {624, 1.72601}, {624.5, 2.47269}, {625, 3.20476}, {625.5, 
  3.79925}, {626, 4.13864}, {626.5, 4.19772}, {627, 3.89868}, {627.5, 
  3.29066}, {628, 2.56193}, {628.5, 1.18217}, {629, 1.201}, {629.5, 
  0.839954}, {630, 0.786096}, {630.5, 1.02266}, {631, 
  1.54216}, {631.5, 2.25694}, {632, 3.00161}, {632.5, 3.64996}, {633, 
  4.10662}, {633.5, 4.25422}, {634, 4.07742}, {634.5, 3.61742}, {635, 
  2.95538}, {635.5, 2.19536}, {636, 1.50027}, {636.5, 0.983518}, {637,
   0.74738}, {637.5, 0.832367}, {638, 1.18611}, {638.5, 
  1.81069}, {639, 2.52052}, {639.5, 3.21332}, {640, 3.83586}, {640.5, 
  4.22302}, {641, 4.26521}, {641.5, 4.04653}, {642, 1.35466}, {642.5, 
  2.86817}, {643, 2.10287}, {643.5, 1.43117}, {644, 0.979356}, {644.5,
   0.746969}, {645, 0.822581}, {645.5, 1.18215}, {646, 
  1.79122}, {646.5, 2.53364}, {647, 3.26476}, {647.5, 3.88628}, {648, 
  4.26317}, {648.5, 4.35906}, {649, 4.14209}, {649.5, 3.64585}, {650, 
  2.99705}, {650.5, 2.26706}, {651, 1.56593}, {651.5, 1.0163}, {652, 
  0.73207}, {652.5, 0.747088}, {653, 1.07065}, {653.5, 1.63029}, {654,
   2.33737}, {654.5, 3.09604}, {655, 3.78087}, {655.5, 4.23351}, {656,
   4.41608}, {656.5, 4.31326}, {657, 3.90086}, {657.5, 3.25933}, {658,
   2.51208}, {658.5, 1.77755}, {659, 1.19039}, {659.5, 0.82135}, {660,
   0.73459}, {660.5, 0.923318}, {661, 1.37076}, {661.5, 
  2.04397}, {662, 2.80493}, {662.5, 3.50803}, {663, 4.05783}, {663.5, 
  4.38846}, {664, 4.44331}, {664.5, 4.18948}, {665, 3.66034}, {665.5, 
  2.97169}, {666, 2.22196}, {666.5, 1.53033}, {667, 1.00316}, {667.5, 
  0.712324}, {668, 0.720476}, {668.5, 1.01816}, {669, 
  1.55374}, {669.5, 2.20475}, {670, 1.29344}, {670.5, 3.62008}, {671, 
  4.15156}, {671.5, 4.42109}, {672, 1.14064}, {672.5, 4.11829}, {673, 
  3.57602}, {673.5, 2.91773}, {674, 2.20852}, {674.5, 1.15511}, {675, 
  1.02009}, {675.5, 0.697501}, {676, 0.667976}, {676.5, 
  0.885184}, {677, 1.38302}, {677.5, 2.03745}, {678, 2.73663}, {678.5,
   3.40918}, {679, 3.99096}, {679.5, 4.35622}, {680, 4.47979}, {680.5,
   1.14244}, {681, 3.95276}, {681.5, 3.37505}, {682, 2.69638}, {682.5,
   2.00051}, {683, 1.37816}, {683.5, 0.907614}, {684, 
  0.677135}, {684.5, 0.689303}, {685, 0.966128}, {685.5, 
  1.43516}, {686, 2.06529}, {686.5, 2.74617}, {687, 3.43241}, {687.5, 
  3.97529}, {688, 4.33397}, {688.5, 4.49717}, {689, 4.43023}, {689.5, 
  4.10693}, {690, 3.57432}, {690.5, 2.92862}, {691, 2.24064}, {691.5, 
  1.57001}, {692, 1.06899}, {692.5, 0.732014}, {693, 
  0.622801}, {693.5, 0.747907}, {694, 1.09798}, {694.5, 
  1.64217}, {695, 2.29531}, {695.5, 2.99002}, {696, 3.61233}, {696.5, 
  4.09516}, {697, 4.40627}, {697.5, 1.44823}, {698, 4.31201}, {698.5, 
  3.95702}, {699, 3.43039}, {699.5, 2.78007}, {700, 2.12133}, {700.5, 
  1.48453}, {701, 0.991509}, {701.5, 0.687136}, {702, 
  0.597239}, {702.5, 0.756349}, {703, 1.11419}, {703.5, 
  1.67803}, {704, 2.29402}, {704.5, 2.93747}, {705, 3.55918}, {705.5, 
  4.07042}, {706, 4.39249}, {706.5, 4.47876}, {707, 4.33559}, {707.5, 
  1.19955}, {708, 3.47446}, {708.5, 2.85115}, {709, 2.17851}, {709.5, 
  1.55004}, {710, 1.04355}, {710.5, 0.689702}, {711, 
  0.576168}, {711.5, 0.721066}, {712, 1.02222}, {712.5, 
  1.51412}, {713, 2.14927}, {713.5, 2.78333}, {714, 1.33666}, {714.5, 
  3.881}, {715, 4.24701}, {715.5, 4.39667}, {716, 4.33523}, {716.5, 
  4.06193}, {717, 3.60485}, {717.5, 2.99235}, {718, 2.35411}, {718.5, 
  1.73758}, {719, 1.20277}, {719.5, 0.794537}, {720, 
  0.592862}, {720.5, 0.602188}, {721, 0.813372}, {721.5, 
  1.19044}, {722, 1.76616}, {722.5, 2.43174}, {723, 3.06058}, {723.5, 
  3.61876}, {724, 4.02438}, {724.5, 4.30431}, {725, 4.35566}, {725.5, 
  4.22278}, {726, 3.89374}, {726.5, 3.41091}, {727, 2.79258}, {727.5, 
  2.15396}, {728, 1.57597}, {728.5, 1.09347}, {729, 0.741331}, {729.5,
   0.57493}, {730, 0.589862}, {730.5, 0.802169}, {731, 
  1.18632}, {731.5, 1.68788}, {732, 2.28042}, {732.5, 2.88748}, {733, 
  3.44387}, {733.5, 3.88005}, {734, 4.18915}, {734.5, 4.29245}, {735, 
  4.22213}, {735.5, 3.98239}, {736, 3.56951}, {736.5, 3.04543}, {737, 
  2.50588}, {737.5, 1.93903}, {738, 1.41318}, {738.5, 0.968273}, {739,
   0.659758}, {739.5, 0.527524}, {740, 0.589017}, {740.5, 
  0.816269}, {741, 1.1854}, {741.5, 1.67988}, {742, 2.24236}, {742.5, 
  2.79845}, {743, 3.31363}, {743.5, 3.75008}, {744, 4.046}, {744.5, 
  4.19039}, {745, 4.20304}, {745.5, 3.99817}, {746, 3.67289}, {746.5, 
  3.20596}, {747, 1.26866}, {747.5, 2.1237}, {748, 1.58925}, {748.5, 
  1.11973}, {749, 0.775268}, {749.5, 0.5622}, {750, 0.512913}, {750.5,
   0.622943}, {751, 0.864436}, {751.5, 1.25483}, {752, 
  1.75557}, {752.5, 2.25953}, {753, 1.27832}, {753.5, 3.27403}, {754, 
  3.68111}, {754.5, 3.98347}, {755, 4.10839}, {755.5, 4.09297}, {756, 
  3.91136}, {756.5, 3.58602}, {757, 3.13645}, {757.5, 2.64106}, {758, 
  2.13768}, {758.5, 1.61639}, {759, 1.14512}, {759.5, 0.789583}, {760,
   0.576474}, {760.5, 0.491561}, {761, 0.557119}, {761.5, 
  0.771409}, {762, 1.10466}, {762.5, 1.56486}, {763, 2.05591}, {763.5,
   2.58492}, {764, 3.06096}, {764.5, 3.46366}, {765, 3.77391}, {765.5,
   3.95108}, {766, 3.98006}, {766.5, 3.86158}, {767, 3.58974}, {767.5,
   3.23021}, {768, 2.78028}, {768.5, 2.28118}, {769, 1.77211}, {769.5,
   1.30314}, {770, 0.906483}};
plotData = ListLinePlot[Sort[data]]

fourierdata = Abs@Fourier[data[[All, 2]], FourierParameters -> {0, .2}];
ListLinePlot[fourierdata, PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 60}}]
```

[A link to the same post in the Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2553289)

Comment: Please add links between this and the cross-post on Wolfram Community

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel Lichtblau, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Copy the link from the Community post to clipboard, use the Edit button under your MSE post, and paste the Community link in with a short note. Or make it a hot link using bracket-parens notation (you may have to look up how that works). Then do likewise for the other post.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a logarithmic plot in dB of the squared magnitude of the fourier transform by:

Periodogram[data[[All, 2]]]

[image]

The frequency axis ends with 1/2, what is the highest frequency compatible with the sample rate, that is 2 points per periode. In your case you have 2 points per time unit.

We have a peak at approx. 0.052. To get the real frequency we have to take the inverse and divide by 2:

```
1/(0.052 2)
9.615
```

Therefore, we have a frequency of approx. 9.6 Hz

The phase and amplitude you get best from using "Fourier", as Ulrich Neumann showed, and pick the 2 components pertaining to the above frequency. Phase and amplitude are obtained from the coefficients.

Comment: Looking at the time plot I would expect roughly  `~11 periods` in the time range `500<t<550`, dominant frequency follows to `~.22/s` I think.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel Huber and Ulrich Neuman. But do you know how I can plot the amplitudes in frequency domain, and to look like in the second picture of my post?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question...

If you are looking for the list of frequencies try

```
t = data[[All, 1]];  (* [seconds] *)
T = t[[-1]] - t[[1]]
index = Range[0, Length[data] - 1];
f = 1/T index;  (* frequency [1/s]*)
ft=Fourier[data[[All, 2]],FourierParameters -> { -1, -1}]

ListLinePlot[{f, Abs[ft]} // Transpose,PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel->{"frequency","Abs[Fourier[...]]"} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich Neumann. I am not sure, but I think that there should be one central amplitude, which consist all the frequencies and at least one more frequency which is smaller than the central one. After FFT is performed on a curve to extract the characteristic frequencies. The amplitude curve should be normalized, and the frequencies should be shifted to obtain a centered x-scale.